# How do I complete the Old Goat quest in Goat MMO Simulator?

Tags: android, goat-simulator

I know where Old Mountain is. I know how to get him. But how do I complete the quest if I cannot bring items in my inventory over to Goatwind? There is no good explanation online for doing this.

I am running the mobile version on Android.

Answer (score 1):

The Old Goat achievement is obtainable by going through the portal in the Entrance and getting through every trap to get to his room, where you them must "kill" him to get the achievement. I'm writing from the perspective of a PC Player, so if it doesn't work, I apologise. I will go through the game on mobile and give you a better explanation if there's anything different to the PC by getting that achievement.

EDIT 1: You only need to enter his room, not kill him. That is a quest, not an achievement. Sorry.

Comment: After trying, I couldn't get the achievement. It could only be for PC? Or you may have to unlock other achievements before you can unlock Old Goat achievement.

Comment: Doesn’t work for me on PC.

Answer (score -3):

You need to find Old Goat's room in Old Goat Mountain. There is also a quest to kill Old Goat.

[source](http://goatsimulator.gamepedia.com/Old_Goat_(Achievement))

Comment: And where is that?  C'mon, you can do better than parrot a wiki with the achievement's source.

Comment: They said they knew were that was, and they knew how to get him, so this answer isn't very useful.